# If "security.authentication.manager" service is deprecated, how to replace it?

Tags: php, symfony, security, symfony5

My application (based on the Symfony5 framework) used a traditional guard authenticator. Users login with a traditional login form. All was created via the maker bundle and the make:auth command.

I'm trying the 5.3.0-RC1, and I discover that the guard authenticator will be deprecated. So, I'm trying to migrate my security to [use the new authenticator-based security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html#authenticators-removed-authentication-providers). But I loosed my csrf token, at the first step.

Here is the core of my AppAuthenticator class extending the new AbstractAuthenticator:

```php
    //...
    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $password = $request->request->get('password');
        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        $csrfToken = $request->request->get('_csrf_token'); //<========HERE THE CSRF TOKEN IS GOOD !

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $email
        );

        $userBadge = new UserBadge($email, function ($userIdentifier) {
            return $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $userIdentifier]);
        });

        return new Passport($userBadge, new PasswordCredentials($password), [
            new PasswordUpgradeBadge($password, $this->userRepository),
            new CsrfTokenBadge('login', $csrfToken)
        ]);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate(self::DASHBOARD_ROUTE));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        dd($request, $exception); //<==== IN THE REQUEST THE CSRF IS GOOD, IN THE EXCEPTION THE CSRF IS NULL !!!!

        return null;
    }
```

It seems that request does forward the csrf token (Here is the dump of the request instance):

```
AppAuthenticator.php on line 70:
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#5 ▼
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#20 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#16 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [▼
      "email" => "moderator@example.org"
      "password" => "test"
      "_csrf_token" => "e8695dd50d110ac0631.skdbZJaWOnU3ckQDF_e0k64-RfUo1qcqrcyv0X8_yRo.3g8eE6HjcwFSKyxwfKH_289qB7tM5-tmlZ_Bi00Kmiz3EhYwof4KGE8gKw"
      "_remember_me" => "on"
    ]
  }
```

But it seems that in the exception, the csrf token is null!!!

```
AppAuthenticator.php on line 70:
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException {#924 ▼
  -token: null
  #message: "Invalid CSRF token."
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security-http/EventListener/CsrfProtectionListener.php"
  #line: 51
```

I don't find my error, but I guess it comes from these lines:

I read [about passport badge](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html#passport-badges) that there is one unique id per form and on uniq token per request:

> Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge
> Automatically validates CSRF tokens for this authenticator during authentication. The constructor requires a token ID (unique per form)
> and CSRF token (unique per request). See How to Implement CSRF
> Protection.

Perhaps my error is in this line: new CsrfTokenBadge('login', $csrfToken)
But what is this id??? I tried login, login_form, without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should match whatever `id` you used in your login form (`csrf_token('id')`). As you originally used `MakerBundle` to generate the form, the value should be `authenticate`.